# Need to configure Bitcoin RPC bitcoin.conf for production ecosystem

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

hello I'm building a little **exchange** website and need a simple solution to integrate via api, I'm looking for something that allows bitcoin payments to be sent to bitcoin addresses for users who will choose to buy bitcoin on my website. and a solution that can provide a bitcoin address to every user who chooses to sell bitcoin on my website. after much research i found **bitcoin json rpc**, and many tutorials on how to install and use it. now i need some help to configure my bitcoin rpc node so that it can meet my production needs. Do you advise me to run a full node or pruned node for this project and what is the best way to send transactions for this kind of project while considering the fees for each sending of payment **(createrawtransaction or sendtoaddress?)**

below my bitcoin configuration

```
rpcuser = bitcoin
rpcpassword = password
rpcallowip = 0.0.0.0 / 0
rpcport = 8332
main.rpcbind = 0.0.0.0
daemon = 1
prune = 0
minrelaytxfee = 2500
maxconnections = 20
maxuploadtarget = 250
mintxfee = 0.0001
txindex = 1
txconfirmtarget = 6
keypool = 10000
```

Comment: Pruned node is also a full node because it fully validates all blocks during initial sync. IMO an exchange should not use pruned node because of some limitations. Example: txindex=1 will not work on pruned node

Comment: thank you for your answer, concerning the way to send the payments and the way to manage the fees, what can you advise me?

Comment: `createrawtransaction` followed by `fundrawtransaction`, `signrawtransactionwithwallet` and `sendrawtransaction` should work